# To fail to do verb: そこなう or そこねる

Tags: grammar

> ポッタ一を殺しそこねた時、...
> when he failed to kill Potter ...

So I'm familiar with adding そこなう to the  masu-stem of a verb with the meaning of "fail to do verb". I'm reasonably sure that a similar meaning is intended in the sentence above, but I'm confused to see そこねる. I understand that そこねる means "to harm" but this makes absolutely no sense in the context.

Do そこねる and そこなう both have the meaning of "fail to do verb", or do we have a typo in this sentence, or is there something else I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do そこねる and そこなう both have the meaning of "fail to do verb"

Yes, they do.  [連用形]+そこねる can also mean "fail to do". From 明鏡国語辞典:

> そこねる【損ねる】
> **「損なう」②③・の、ややくだけた言い方。**
> 「気分[美観]をー」**「つかみー・食べー」**

> そこなう【損なう】
> 《動詞の連用形に付いて複合動詞を作る》
> ❶ …することに失敗する。また、間違えて…する。**…損ねる。**「取り[打ち]ー」...
> ❷ …する機会をのがす。**…損ねる。**「食べー」...
> ❸ …するはずのところをしないでしまう。また、危うく…しそうになる。**…損ねる。**「死にー」...

---

By the way,

> そこねる means "to harm"

そこなう can also mean "to harm".

> そこな・う【損なう】
>  〘他〙
> ❶ 〔やや古風な言い方で〕傷つけてだめにする。損傷する。損ずる*。「過って器物をー」...
> ❷ 健康や気分を悪くする。害する。**損ねる。**「過労で健康をー」...
> ❸ 本来的に備わった美質や機能などを傷つけてだめにする。**損ねる。**「ビルが街の美観をー」...

---

<sub>*ちなみに、「損ずる」・「損じる」もあります。</sub>

> <sub>そんじる【損じる】
>
> ⇨損ずる「書きー」</sub>

> <sub>そんずる【損ずる】
>
> 〘自他〙　
> ❶ ものが傷つき壊れる。また、ものを傷つけ壊す。**そこなう。** ...「転倒して衣服をー」...
>
> ❷ 物事の状態などが悪くなる。また、物事の状態などを悪くする。**そこなう。**...「先方の機嫌をー」...
>
> 《動詞の連用形に付いて複合動詞を作る》**…しそこなう。**「言いー・打ちー」「急いては事をしー」</sub>

Comment: 「書き損じる/損ずる」「書き損なう」「書き損ねる」は良さそうなのに、「書き損じハガキ」を「書き損ねハガキ」「書き損ないハガキ」って言わないですね。「死に損ねる」「死に損なう」はいいですけど、「死に損じる/損ずる」はないですね。名詞は「死に[損]{ぞこ}ない」で、「死に損ね」じゃないです。なんででしょう？